# ASP.Net membership login issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

I am trying to run two web application using the same ASP.NET membership provider database that comes with MVC3. So two web app runs side by side and they both has the same connection to the same membership databse. The problem now is, I can only login at one app and get automatically log out at the other. However, the feature I want is, if I log into either one, I get automatically log into the other.

I was wondering what the trick is to enable this feature.

thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Forms Authentication users are tracked with cookies. Cookies are by default restricted only to the application that emitted them. And because of this the other application cannot see the authentication cookie created by the first. So for example if you have the two applications hosted respectively on `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com` you could set the `domain` property of the cookie in `web.config` of both applications to `example.com`:

```
<forms
    loginUrl="/login/index.mcp"
    requireSSL="true"
    protection="All"
    timeout="120"
    domain="example.com"
/>
```

This way the cookie will be shared among those two applications and you will be able to achieve Single Sign On.

Comment: Well, I tested it and it didn't work on my machine. What I do is to we a web site in my IIS with domain "lwww.domain.com", then deploy one app into the root, another into a seperate web application under the root. They used differnt app pool. I log into the root one but didn't get auto logged into the child one.... Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @user299230, what did you set the `domain` property in web.config to? When you inspect with FireBug or Fiddler the requests do you see the authentication cookie being sent to the second application? Also try setting the sama machine keys in for both applications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Finanlly I fixed it.
My application runs under the same domain so domain is not a problem (But Thank you very much, Darin).
The problem is:
IIS by default generate differnt machine key for differnt web application. So I have to specify the same machine key in web.config explicitly~!